# Using example for strategies that return class instances

Tags: python-hypothesis

I have

```
class A(st.SearchStrategy):
  def do_draw(self, data):
     return object_a(b=st.integers(), c=st.boolean()...)

class B(st.SearchStrategy):
  def do_draw(self, data):
     return object_a(d=st.boolean(), e=st.boolean()...)

@given(a=A(), b=B())
def test_A_and_B(a, b):
  ...
```

How I make sure that a test case of

```
a = A(b=5, c=True)
# b can be anything
```

and a test case of

```
a = A(b=10, c=True)
b = B(c=True, d=<can be either T or F>)
```

get generate?

I know about @example. Would this be correct?

```
@given(a=A(), b=B())
@example(a=A(b=10, c=True), b=B(c=True, d=False)
# not sure how to set d to be either true or false
def test_A_and_B(a, b):
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

> **DO NOT INHERIT FROM SEARCHSTRATEGY.**
>   It is private, internal code that we might change at any time.  You're using it wrong anyway!

Instead, you should compose your strategy from the [*documented* functions](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html) in `hypothesis.strategies`.  For example, you can define a strategy for making instances of `object_a` using [`builds()`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.builds) like so:

```
builds(object_a, b=st.integers(), c=st.booleans(), ...)
```

An `@example` is a single exact input, so you'd use it twice to check d both True and False:

```
@example(a=object_a(b=10, c=True), b=object_b(c=True, d=True)
@example(a=object_a(b=10, c=True), b=object_b(c=True, d=False)
```

If you don't care about the value of `b` at all, just define an example with the default value for that argument.

All together, that would look like:

```
@given(
    a=builds(object_a, b=st.integers(), c=st.booleans()), 
    b=builds(object_b, d=st.booleans(), e=st.booleans()
)
@example(a=object_a(b=5, c=True), b=None)  # assuming b=None is valid
@example(a=object_a(b=10, c=True), b=object_b(d=True, e=True))
@example(a=object_a(b=10, c=True), b=object_b(d=True, e=False))
def test_A_and_B(a, b):
    ...
```

Hope that helps :-)